# JScrollPane is not adding to my JList.

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

Im trying to add a Scroll bar to my JList. I want only 4 headings to be available on my JList at a time. When I add a JList and run my program, the JList disappears from the screen. Can someone help me fix this problem? I am using Java Eclipse.

This is my code:

```
songList1 = new JList (ListData);
songList1.setVisibleRowCount(4);
songList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
songList1.setBounds(300,100,100,200);
panel.add(new JScrollPane(songList1);
```

Comment: Where are you creating the `ListModel`? Are you sure is correct? Also, why are you setting bounds on the JList? Should be on the top component (JScrollPane in your case), but better would be to use layouts.

Comment: Yea it correct, it works if i remove the JScrollPane. Otherwise it doesnt.

Comment: Don't set the bounds on the list and try it to see if it works.

Comment: Do you call at the end `panel.pack();` and `panel.setVisible(true);`?

Comment: I have panel.setVisible(true); All my other 1000 lines of code work. Its just this last thing i need. All buttons, texfields appear on the screen

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:

1. set panel's layout or
2. set scroll panes bounding area by scrollPane.setBounds()

Answer (score -1):

Just an oversight:

```
songList1 = new JList(ListData);
songList1.setVisibleRowCount(4);
songList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
JScrollPane songList1ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(songList1)
//songList1ScrollPane.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 200);
songList1ScrollPane.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 200);
panel.setLayout(null); // Absolute positioning
panel.add(songList1ScrollPane);
...
add(panel); // Or so
```

Of course the panel should have an appropiate layout.

Comment: @AndrewThompson the code uses `setBounds`, and already seems to encompass many components. So it seems that error searching is more important, temporarily trying things out. Will take your respectful critics to heart. _Absolute positioning does not fit every platform, and needs more maintenance on positions - unnecessarily._